# After i enable a terms and conditions its reflects a error in one page checkout in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, onepage-checkout, terms-and-conditions

In magento 2  after  i enable a terms and conditions its reflects a error in one page checkout

Refer Image: https://prnt.sc/nw9ivm

Comment: Did you set terms and conditions as a required?

Comment: Does `terms and conditions` checkbox show on checkout page?

Comment: yes its shown in checkout page

Comment: One page checkout is not Magento 2 default feature. Please contact to  your extension provider regarding this issue.

Comment: your screenshot does not show terms and conditions checkbox.